# How to pass a url with selenium sendkey in c #?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem in passing the `url` in selenium, in the sendkey I insert the `url` to use example:

```
sendkey("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

in the output comes out:

```
https: --stackoverflow.com-
```

how to do?

Comment: What is the symbol for the Shift key when sending keys?

Comment: sorry I did not understand the question, i use selenium and i passing with the sendkey this url https://stackoverflow.com/ and i output comes out: https: --stackoverflow.com-, I would need it to be output https://stackoverflow.com/, how to do ?

Comment: What I mean is that if you consider an english keyboard, the `-` key on the keyboard doubles as the `/` keyboard (I think) *if you press the Shift key while pressing it*. As such I'm wondering if the `sendkey` function needs to consider how to press the Shift key for you. If the `sendkey` function is **correctly** named, it's not sending literal text to the application, it's **pressing actual keys**, and I am just wondering if you need to tell it to press actual Shift keys during the replay.